# Calculate #'s of possibilities

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I have a set of `n` antenna's of which `m` are defective, leaving `n-m` in working conditions. The defective and non-defective antenna's are to be considered indistinguishable (order of them is not important). How many linear orderning are there in which **no two consecutive antenna's are defective?**

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: How can there be no two consecutive antennas, if all you have is antennas? What's between them?

Comment: @MattiP. My bad. It is **no two consecutive antenna's are defective**. I have updated the question

Comment: So basically you can reduce this to a question about 0's and 1s, where you have a fixed length of a string and you know how many 0's and 1's you have there. And you also know that there are no occurrances of two 1's next to each other. I would start by first laying out the 0's , and then thinking how I can put the 1's so that they don't go next to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can approach this problem , consider the $n-m$ working antennas placed in a long queue this will generate $n-m+1$ spaces between them , of these spaces we have to choose any $m$ spaces and place defective antennas in those locations ! thus ensuring that no two effective antennas are together

the answer is : $ \binom{n-m+1}{m} $